# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Can somebody help with this issue? It shows no module named 'numpy', but I have already installed and imported it in the notebook.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 223.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 223.0 (TID 867, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1354, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 147, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 580, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 869, in _parse_datatype_json_string
    return _parse_datatype_json_value(json.loads(json_string))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 886, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return _all_complex_types[tpe].fromJson(json_value)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 577, in fromJson
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 577, in <listcomp>
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 434, in fromJson
    _parse_datatype_json_value(json["type"]),
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 888, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return UserDefinedType.fromJson(json_value)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 736, in fromJson
    m = __import__(pyModule, globals(), locals(), [pyClass])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.base import Estimator, Model, Transformer, UnaryTransformer
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.param.shared import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor247.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1354, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 147, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 580, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 869, in _parse_datatype_json_string
    return _parse_datatype_json_value(json.loads(json_string))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 886, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return _all_complex_types[tpe].fromJson(json_value)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 577, in fromJson
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 577, in <listcomp>
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 434, in fromJson
    _parse_datatype_json_value(json["type"]),
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 888, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return UserDefinedType.fromJson(json_value)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 736, in fromJson
    m = __import__(pyModule, globals(), locals(), [pyClass])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.base import Estimator, Model, Transformer, UnaryTransformer
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.param.shared import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: To provide you a more detailed answer it would help if you post more information about your setup. How are you running the notebook  - locally or on some cloud provider? How have you installed numpy? 
Best is you create a demo project on github

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have installed the module on your local machine. 
Spark code in your notebook creates only a DAG - a plan how to execute the code
on multiple remote nodes.

If those nodes are using numpy code code e.g in rdd map function or a dataframe udf, each of those worker nodes needs numpy.

It can either be installed on provisionining or submitted as a zip  file with with spark-submit.